# Why is the browser shrinking the image despite its container appearing big enough to contain its full size?

Tags: html, css

I have an image of resolution 211 by 135 and its div container is 215 by 140. Why is it that Chrome displays the image as 192 by 122?

I am editing a singular page on Wordpress and this is the HTML and CSS code that I am able to manipulate:

```
<div class="proven-struct-small">
<img src="https://provenwealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/folded-euros.jpg" />
</div>
<h4 class="proven-horizontal-line-title"><a href="/wealth-management/managed-portfolios/">Managed Portfolios</a></h4>
```

```
.proven-struct-small {
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 140px;
    width: 215px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your picture size? Because it's currently 404 so can't check, and if I try your code with an actual 211x135 image, then it appears with correct aspect ratio and no crop. Could also be CSS elsewhere fiddling with image dimensions...

Comment: @julien.giband It's not 404 for me (and I checked while logged out of WordPress admin). maybe you pasted the link incorrectly? either way, it's nice to know that the code works vanilla. I'll see if there's CSS somewhere else that is affecting it.

Comment: Sorry but I just tried again and https://provenwealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/folded-euros.jpg does give me a 404 page instead of an image

Comment: @julien.giband that truly is strange. I have connected my laptop to my phone's hotspot and I clicked the link and it takes me to the image. i am not sure why others are not able to see it. thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Yes, the image is 404. Is it possible that it is still in your browser cache, but no longer there (or no longer has proper permissions).  Try an incognito browser tab and see if you can still see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that WordPress lied about the size of the image after being uploaded. The metadata of the image says 211 by 135 but I think a plugin decreased its size 192 by 122. It's not my code that's the problem...

EDIT: WordPress's interface did not accurately represent the true contents of the Web Server. Therefore the link generated by the interface would sometimes point to the wrong image or no image at all on the server. What a relief!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `height:100%` to the image in CSS so it automatically takes the entire height of its parent, in this case the div, like this:

```css
.proven-struct-small {
  padding-top: 0;
  height: 140px;
  width: 215px;
}

.proven-struct-small img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="proven-struct-small">
  <img src="https://provenwealth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/folded-euros.jpg" />
</div>
<h4 class="proven-horizontal-line-title">
  <a href="/wealth-management/managed-portfolios/">Managed Portfolios</a>
</h4>
```

As another user pointed out your image link is broken but I tried with a different one and seems to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks but setting height to 100% stretches the image past 211 by 135 which is a bit less than ideal.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't solve your issue. This is wild guess without being able to see the image, but would `max-height: 135px` help?

Comment: turns out that WordPress lied about the size of the image after being uploaded. the metadata of the image says 211 by 135 but I think a plugin decreased its size 192 by 122.